# Dynamic filtering with an ItemsControl combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have this situation where I want to display a list of Administration objects and a `ComboBox` for each Administration. Inside this `ComboBox` I want a list with Employees belonging to this Administration, along with an empty option. So I need to filter based on Administration.

So far I've come up with the following code (note: object names have been translated)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="listAdministrations" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllAdministrations}" Margin="0,0,0,6">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <TextBox Content="{Binding Path=AdministrationName}" />

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="14,0,0,0">
                    <Label>Declares under:</Label>
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="DisplayFullName">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <!-- empty option -->
                                <model:Employee DisplayFullName="-" />
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource employeeCV}}"/>
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The static resource `employeeCV` is a `CollectionViewSource` with a Filter event attached. But I have to somehow pass the current Administration in the ItemsControl loop to this event. In data binding, this translates to `{Binding Path=.}` within the `ItemsControl`. The sender object is my `CollectionViewSource` but this provides no useful data.

Something like this:

```
private void EmployeeAdministrationFilter( object sender, FilterEventArgs e )
    {
        Employee employee = ( Employee )e.Item;
        Administration administration; // how do I pass the administration to this filter?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do exactly what you ask, but I can suggest an alternate approach: create an extension method for your Administration class. This method creates a filtered collection view and returns it. You can then bind to the result of the method.

Comment: Antonmarkov,

do you mean something like this: (pseudo-code)

    public class Administration
    {
        public CollectionViewSource CollectionViewSource
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public Administration()
        {
            CollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
            CollectionViewSource.Filter += EmployeeAdministrationFilter;
        }

        private void EmployeeAdministrationFilter( object sender, FilterEventArgs e )
        {
             // filter stuff
             // this = Administration
        }
}

Comment: Yes, if you can modify Administration, then you can just add the property directly. You should probably use a plain CollectionView instead of CollectionViewSource though. CollectionViewSource is a markup extension for use in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try that : http://dotnetexplorer.blog.com/2011/04/07/wpf-itemscontrol-generic-staticreal-time-filter-custom-control-presentation/

This is a generic, dynamic, full XAML declarative itemscontrol filter user control. It can filter datagrid, listbox,combobox, etc...

Hope this helps